# Navigationdrawer remove gray bar on top

Tags: android

[image]

I would like to remove the gray bar on top of my drawer. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my DrawerLayout.